# How to create a column for ordering values

Tags: data

I have a dataset, where some data has to be ranked in regard to the number of ranking of the total dataset. I've made a simple example below:

```
names = {"Set A", "Set B", "Set C"};
values = {67, 80, 50};
{names, values} // Transpose
```

I would like to add a 3rd column, which described the rank of the total column. I've tried with `RankedMax` but without any luck. To be more exactly, the matrix below shows my problem, where the third column is ranking the highest to lowest value.

$$\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 \text{Set 1} & 67 & 2 \\
 \text{Set 2} & 80 & 1 \\
 \text{Set 3} & 50 & 3 \\
\end{array}
\right)$$

How can create such a column?

Comment: Does `{names, values, Ordering[values]} // Transpose` work to get what you need?

Comment: @kguler this is exactly what I needed. Very Simple I see. Thank you. Maybe I should delete this post? I suppose this will not add any value to others, since it is this simple...

Comment: @kguler I guess that should be `Ordering[-values]`, given that the OP wants a descending sort

Comment: @kguler After further investigation, I can see that Ordering doesn't solve the problem for all kinds of dataset, especially when they become larger than this example..

Comment: Jens, what kind of issues do you get with `Ordering` for larger datasets?

Comment: It is very difficult to find the exact issue, but somehow it doesn't work properly. At least when I trey these as value:
{0.109892,0.153395,0.263218,0.0976219,0.26596,0.230077,0.235412,0.201642,0.0702126,0.134909,0.155424,0.263319,0.224367,0.253994,0.117316,0.0733121,0.190985,0.305341,0.139088,0.190262,0.00999462,0.20669,-0.00893785,0.087579,0.175154,0.0882176,0.193825,0.236279,-0.0883605,0.229773,0.292539,0.0971533,0.0613749,0.298706,0.121186,0.148439,0.000799421,0.284733,0.335953,-0.0610469,0.14451,0.0784617,0.136533,0.37428,0.181673,0.262039,-0.217684,-0.13403,0.0359772,0.179099}

Comment: Jens, you are right - `Ordering` is not what you need ;you need the rank in the ordered version of the input list. Please check the posted answer if that is what you need and it works for your other datasets.

Comment: .. also check `listB = the larger list in your last comment`  to make sure it is not corrupted. As is, while most of its entries are `Real`  some are not.

Comment: The rankF function is still not sorting correctly. When I take Max[listB] it is not what rankF suggest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The data set you pasted in your comment below contained several invisible non-ASCII characters.

They are revealed using `ToCharacterCode`

```
dataString = "{0.109892,0.153395,0.263218,0.0976219,0.26596,0.230077,0.235412,0.201642,0.07021‌​26,0.134909,0.155424,0.263319,0.224367,0.253994,0.117316,0.0733121,0.190985,0.305‌​341,0.139088,0.190262,0.00999462,0.20669,-0.00893785,0.087579,0.175154,0.0882176,‌​0.193825,0.236279,-0.0883605,0.229773,0.292539,0.0971533,0.0613749,0.298706,0.121‌​186,0.148439,0.000799421,0.284733,0.335953,-0.0610469,0.14451,0.0784617,0.136533,‌​0.37428,0.181673,0.262039,-0.217684,-0.13403,0.0359772,0.179099}"

ToCharacterCode[dataString]

(* {123, 48, 46, 49, 48, 57, 56, 57, 50, 44, 48, 46, 49, 53, etc. 49, 8204, \
8203, 50, 54, 44, etc. 48, 53, 8204, 8203,  etc. 44, 8204, 8203, 48, \
etc., 49, 8204, 8203, 49, 56, etc. 57, 125} *)
```

Convert to real ASCII:

```
data = DeleteCases[ToCharacterCode[dataString], _?(# > 127 &)] //FromCharacterCode // ToExpression
(* {0.109892, 0.153395, 0.263218, 0.0976219, 0.26596, 0.230077, \
0.235412, 0.201642, 0.0702126, 0.134909, 0.155424, 0.263319, \
0.224367, 0.253994, 0.117316, 0.0733121, 0.190985, 0.305341, \
0.139088, 0.190262, 0.00999462, 0.20669, -0.00893785, 0.087579, \
0.175154, 0.0882176, 0.193825, 0.236279, -0.0883605, 0.229773, \
0.292539, 0.0971533, 0.0613749, 0.298706, 0.121186, 0.148439, \
0.000799421, 0.284733, 0.335953, -0.0610469, 0.14451, 0.0784617, \
0.136533, 0.37428, 0.181673, 0.262039, -0.217684, -0.13403, \
0.0359772, 0.179099} *)
```

Ranking can be done using `Ordering`:

```
Ordering@Ordering@-data
(* {34, 26, 9, 35, 7, 14, 13, 18, 41, 31, 25, 8, 16, 11, 33, \
40, 20, 3, 29, 21, 44, 17, 46, 38, 24, 37, 19, 12, 48, 15, 5, 36, 42, \
4, 32, 27, 45, 6, 2, 47, 28, 39, 30, 1, 22, 10, 50, 49, 43, 23} *)
```

To show that this works, let's sort the paired data and ranking:

```
Transpose[{data, Ordering@Ordering@-data}] // Sort // Reverse
(* {{0.37428, 1}, {0.335953, 2}, {0.305341, 3}, {0.298706, 
  4}, {0.292539, 5}, {0.284733, 6}, {0.26596, 7}, {0.263319, 
  8}, {0.263218, 9}, {0.262039, 10}, {0.253994, 11}, {0.236279, 
  12}, {0.235412, 13}, {0.230077, 14}, {0.229773, 15}, {0.224367, 
  16}, {0.20669, 17}, {0.201642, 18}, {0.193825, 19}, {0.190985, 
  20}, {0.190262, 21}, {0.181673, 22}, {0.179099, 23}, {0.175154, 
  24}, {0.155424, 25}, {0.153395, 26}, {0.148439, 27}, {0.14451, 
  28}, {0.139088, 29}, {0.136533, 30}, {0.134909, 31}, {0.121186, 
  32}, {0.117316, 33}, {0.109892, 34}, {0.0976219, 35}, {0.0971533, 
  36}, {0.0882176, 37}, {0.087579, 38}, {0.0784617, 39}, {0.0733121, 
  40}, {0.0702126, 41}, {0.0613749, 42}, {0.0359772, 43}, {0.00999462,
   44}, {0.000799421, 45}, {-0.00893785, 46}, {-0.0610469, 
  47}, {-0.0883605, 48}, {-0.13403, 49}, {-0.217684, 50}} *)
```